# Is it possible to implement Ray-tracing into real-time game engines?

Tags: c++, 3d, shader, hlsl, compute-shader

As far as I know, there are two ways of drawing a triangle: rasterization and ray-tracing. Ray-tracing is time-consuming because it needs to shot many rays into a 3D scene and calculate intersection points. I'm aware that many animation films making companies such as Pixar use ray-tracing to create photo-realistic images. What I want to know is, is it possible to implement Ray-tracing into real-time game engines? Games are needed to be interactive. To create a sense of motion, drawing at least 30 images per frame is required.

Comment: Yea the new RTX cards whole USP is Real-time Raytracing.

Comment: @Faraz Thanks. So, is it impossible to implement ray-tracing into real-time game engines without RTX cards and the whole USP?

Comment: it is definitely possible just that RTX uses specialized hardware to optimize its calculations (RT Cores) and employs some De-noising algorithms to sharpen the image. I have seen people implement rudimentary realtime Ray-Tracing all on the CPU. Remember that Ray-tracing is just one part to make beautiful graphics, De-noising, Anti-aliasing, post-processing etc also require processor time.

Comment: @Faraz Thanks a lot! I will study RT cores and De-noising algorithms.